# Do I have to set both sides for a bidirectional relationship?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, derby

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private long id;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(final long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a")
    List<B> bs;

    public List<B> getBs() {
        return bs;
    }

    public void setBs(final List<B> bs) {
        this.bs = bs;
    }
}
@Entity
public class B {
    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private long id;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(final long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable
    A a;

    public A getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(final A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

To establish the relationship, I have to call

```
b.setA(a);
a.getBs().add(b);
```

Why is both necessary, Why is it not sufficient to do only

```
b.setA(a);
```

or

```
a.getBs().add(b);
```

?

The relationship is stored in a join table, and `b.setA(a)` will update that join table.

But when I do a query afterwards, `a.getBs()` is empty. Why is that?

Here is a Test case that illustrates the question. Note that the very last assert fails.

```
public class QuickTestAB2 {

    private static String dbUrlBase = "jdbc:derby:testData/db/test.db";

    private static String dbUrlCreate = dbUrlBase + ";create=true";

    private static String dbUrlDrop = dbUrlBase + ";drop=true";

    private EntityManagerFactory factory;

    private EntityManager em;

    public Map<String, String> createPersistenceMap(final String dbUrl) {
        final Map<String, String> persistenceMap = new HashMap<>();
        persistenceMap.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", dbUrl);
        return persistenceMap;
    }

    public void dropDatabase() throws Exception {
        if (em != null && em.isOpen()) {
            em.close();
        }
        if (factory != null && factory.isOpen()) {
            factory.close();
        }
        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrlDrop)) {

        } catch (final SQLException e) {
            // always

        }
    }

    public void deleteDatabase() throws Exception {
        dropDatabase();
        final File file = new File("testData/db/test.db");
        if (file.exists()) {
            FileUtils.forceDelete(file);
        }
    }

    public void createNewDatabase() throws SQLException, IOException {

        FileUtils.forceMkdir(new File("testData/db"));
        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrlCreate)) {

        }
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass01() throws Exception {
        Tests.enableLog4J();
        JPATests.enableJPA();

    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownAfterClass01() throws Exception {

    }

    @Before
    public void setUp01() throws Exception {

        deleteDatabase();
        createNewDatabase();
        final Map<String, String> map = createPersistenceMap(dbUrlCreate);
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pu", map);

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown01() throws Exception {
        if (em != null && em.isOpen()) {
            em.close();
        }
        em = null;
        if (factory != null && factory.isOpen()) {
            factory.close();
        }
        factory = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void test01() throws Exception {
        em = factory.createEntityManager();
        final A a = new A();
        final B b = new B();
        b.setA(a);
        try {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(a);
            em.persist(b);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
        em = factory.createEntityManager();
        B b2;
        A a2;
        try {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT b FROM B b");
            b2 = (B) q.getSingleResult();
            q = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM A a");
            a2 = (A) q.getSingleResult();
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
        assertThat(a2, is(not(nullValue())));
        assertThat(b2, is(not(nullValue())));

        assertThat(b2.getA(), is(not(nullValue())));
        assertThat(a2.getBs().isEmpty(), is(false));

    }

}
```

**Motivation:** It can be useful to change a bidirectional relationship by changing "only one side", when the number of `a.Bs` gets large. In this case, an `UPDATE SELECT` query on the owning side is much faster than to call `a.getBs().remove(b)`
See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48692098/update-entity-relationship-via-update-set-query).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in [Nikos Paraskevopoulos' answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48755350/496099), JPA and java objects require you to set both sides of a relationship. As long as you set the owning side, the database will be updated with the relationship changes, but the non-owning side will only reflect what is in the database if you manually set it, or you force it to be refreshed or reloaded. Reading the entity from a separate context does not force reloading, as your JPA provider can use a second level cache; this is the [default](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Caching) in EclipseLink.  Your other read is returning the A from the shared cache, which like your original object, does not have B added to its list of Bs.

The easiest solution is to just set B into A's list upfront. Other options here though would be to force the refresh of A using em.refresh(a) or with a query hint, or disable the shared cached.

Answer (score 9):

There are 2 "facets" in the question: The Java side and the JPA side.

#### Java side

A more complete listing of the code might be:

```
@Entity
class A {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a")
    @JoinTable
    List<B> bs;

    public List<B> getBs() {
        return bs;
    }
    public void setBs(List<B> bs) {
        this.bs = bs;
    }
}

@Entity
class B {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable
    A a;

    public A getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

The JPA entites are still Java objects. If *you* do not instruct Java *explicitly* to, e.g. "add the B in the collection of Bs, when its `a` property is set" it has no reason to do it automatically. Having said that, I have often seen patterns like (skipping null checking for brevity):

```
@Entity
class A {
    ...

    public void addB(B b) {
        bs.add(b);
        b.setA(this);
    }
    public void removeB(B b) {
        if( bs.remove(b) ) {
            b.setA(null);
        }
    }
}
```

#### JPA side

JPA 2.1. specs, ch. 2.9 "Entity Relationships":

> A bidirectional relationship has both an owning side and an inverse (non-owning) side. A unidirectional relationship has only an owning side. The owning side of a relationship determines the updates to the relationship in the database, as described in section 3.2.4.
>
> - The inverse side of a bidirectional relationship must refer to its owning side by use of the `mappedBy` element

In the setup of the question, `B.a` is the owning side because `A.bs` specifies `mappedBy="a"`. The specifications says that the relation will be updated (i.e. an entry in the join table will be inserted) only when the *owning* side is updated. That is why doing `b.setA(a)` updates the join table.

---

After doing the above *and successfully updating the DB*, reading the related A object *fresh from the DB* should fetch the correct `bs` collection. To be sure, first try merging the B, committing the transaction, and fetching A (or refreshing it) in a different transaction. If you want the state of the *Java objects* to be reflected immediately in the same transaction, you have no other option but to set both `b.a` and `a.getBs().add(b)`.

Comment: Many thanks for the great answer! You describe what I was expecting. Nevertheless, I have difficulties to confirm that. See test case in the updated question.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I am not 100% sure, but i bet that you have confused JPA by specifying `@JoinTable` on the not-owning side of the relation, i.e. `A.bs` (see JPA 2.2 spec ch. 11.1.27). You can verify this if you peek at the tables created in the Derby instance of the test code-there should be 2 join tables. Anyway, can you remove the `@JoinTable` from `A.bs` and give it another go?

Comment: Checked, only one table. I also removed the jointable annotation from A.bs, still no success.