# Spring-Data-Jpa save: Related entities saved as null which are not

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity timetable:

```
@Entity @Table(name = TableUtils.TIMETABLE)public class Timetable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -1307879048598194633L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = ColumnUtils.ID)
private long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "timetable", cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
private List<TimetableCell> timetableCells;

public List<TimetableCell> getTimetableCells() {
    return timetableCells;
}

public void setTimetableCells(List<TimetableCell> timetableCells) {
    this.timetableCells = timetableCells;
}
}
```

and an entity timetableCell:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = TableUtils.TIMETABLE_CELL)
public class TimetableCell extends AbstractElement {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -8083688091896353882L;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name = ColumnUtils.WEEK_DAY_ID, nullable = false)
private WeekDay weekDay;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name = ColumnUtils.LESSON_HOUR_ID, nullable = false)
private LessonHour lessonHour;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name = ColumnUtils.TIMETABLE_ID, nullable = false)
private Timetable timetable;

...
}
```

At first I create timetable cells with weekDay and LessonHours. After I set this list to timetable and try to save it. But All timetable cells are saved with null weekDay and null LessonHour.
I debugged it. Before save all fields are set as well.

`timetableRepository.save(timetable);`

Debug result showing following 
[image]

Comment: Make sure you set both sides of the relationship. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48754783/do-i-have-to-set-both-sides-for-a-bidirectional-relationship

Comment: I have set timetable to each timetabeCell and list of timetableCell to timetable. But for timetable cell I set only weekDay field but I dont set timetableCell to weekDay.

Comment: I tried using unidirectional relation between timetableCell and weekDay and got same result again.

Comment: Show the code where you create and set the list to TimeTable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed `Cascade.Persist` from fields in TimetableCell. It works for me but I don't know that what was problem.

Answer (score 2):

**1)** The `timetableCells` are marked with only these cascade types:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "timetable", cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
```

**2)** The week and hour deps have only this:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
```

**3)** If you pass `Timetable` to save method here and it has been persisted before:

```
timetableRepository.save(timetable);
```

Spring Data JPA will not call `persist`, but `merge` instead.

That might be the case why the cascading does not work. If you add this to your config you might get what you need:

```
cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
```