# generated primary key for secondary table coming null on @OneToMany relationship

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-data

I'm trying to do a simple @OneToMany relationship between contract and asset. But when hibernate tries to save , it's comming as null. What am I doing wrong?

```
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "contracts")
public class Contract {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "contractId")
    private List<Asset> assets;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "assets")
public class Asset {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "contractId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Contract contractId;

}
```

```
@Repository
public interface ContractRepository extends CrudRepository<Contract, Integer> {
}
```

```
    private void mapAndSave(ContractDTO contractDTO) {

        Contract contractToSave = new Contract();

        ModelMapper mapper = BiModelMapper.createModelMapperDtoToEntity();
        mapper.map(contractDTO, contractToSave);

        contractRepository.save(contractToSave);
    }
```

Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'contractId' cannot be null

Comment: If you get that error, it means that the `contract` property of the assets is null. It must not be null.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I have to set both sides for a bidirectional relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48754783/do-i-have-to-set-both-sides-for-a-bidirectional-relationship)

Answer (score 0):

The solution I was able to do is change my column table Asset.contractId to NOT NULL. Because Hibernate tries to insert the row, and after that updates the contractId.

And I change to unidirectional relationship, using only @OneToMany on Contract side.