# JPA persists Child Entity without composite key

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities let's call them Parent and Child.

Parent:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@IdClass(ParentId.class)
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "external1_id", nullable = false)
    private External1 external1;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "external2_id", nullable = false)
    private External2 external2;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Child> children = new LinkedHashSet<>();
}
```

Child:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_external1_id", referencedColumnName = "external1_id")
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_external2_id", referencedColumnName = "external2_id")
    private Parent parent;
}
```

Saving:

```
    var external1 = ...
    var external2 = ...
    
    var child1 = new Child();
    var child2 = new Child();

    var list = List.of(child1,child2);


    var parent = new Parent();
    parent.setExternal1(external1);
    parent.setExternal2(external2);
    parent.setChildren(list);

    parentRepository.save(parent);
```

As you can see here I try to automatically insert the children into their respective table, but since it has a reference to the parent it needs to automatically insert the composite key of the parent into the child. This works just fine with a simple primary key (Long). Here it creates a `DataIntegrityViolationException`, because it tries to insert the child as a row (null,null).

I slightly abstracted away the other properties to make the example more clear. How can I fix this?

Comment: You don't appear to be assigning the `parent` property of the children.  You need to do, because `Child` is the owning side of that relationship.  Adding the children to the parent's set of children does not suffice.  In fact,  under some circumstances you can get away without modifying the parent's `children` property on the Java side at all.  See [Do I have to set both sides for a bidirectional relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48754783/2402272)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always provide these methods whenever you are working with a bidirectional association as, otherwise, you risk very [subtle state propagation issues](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-hibernate-synchronize-bidirectional-entity-associations/)

```
public class Parent {
    public void addChild(Child child) {
        children.add(child);
        child.setParent(this);
    }
}
```

Your saving class

```
    var child1 = new Child();
    var child2 = new Child();

    var parent = new Parent();
    parent.addChild(child1);
    parent.addChild(child2);

    parentRepository.save(parent);
```